# Aurelia Custom elments not showing

Tags: aurelia, custom-element

I'm working on an older Aurelia 1 project which earlier today started to give issues. After fiddling and reinstalling node_modules the thing runs but seems not to be loading any components. This is wat my structure looks like:

`- elements
      - form-login
        - form-login.html
        - form-login.js
        - form-login.scss
     - views
       - authentication
         - login.html
         - login.js
         - login.scss`

(There's more but i'll leave that out for now.)

The login.html loads `<form-login>` like this:

```
<template>
    <require from="elements/form-login/form-login"></require>

    <main class="${ navigationInstruction.name }">
        <form-login class="login__form" success.bind="CALLBACK_SUCCESS"></form-login>
    </main>
```

The result is a blank screen, no contents of the `<form-login>` are ever rendered.

I've already found that he require tag should NOT point to the HTML file but to the directory/name of the component but this the case.

The contents of the form-login.js look like this (w/o irrelevant parts):

```
import {bindable, decorators} from 'aurelia-framework';
import './form-login.scss';


/**
 * The application top navigation bar
 */
export const FormLogin = decorators(
  bindable('success')
).on(class {
  // Lots of code in here but constructor() is never fired.
});
```

Comment: Have you tried a relative path? (`from="../../elements/form-login/form-login"`) ?

Comment: Thx for the suggestion, Just tried that, no luck.

Comment: Are you by any chance exporting the element using `export default class FormLogin {}`? If that's not the case, I think you should share a little more of the code in form-login.js and form-login.html

Comment: I'm not using a default here, should I? I've added the contents on top.

Comment: Is it a completely blank screen (e.g. no sign of any part of Aurelia loading) or is just the component in question never loaded?

Comment: None of the compoments was loading I solved it by copying over a staging node_modules directory and run the project using that. Hacky but works for now. Thx all for helping out

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the solution in comments it is an npm issue with `package.lock.json` file.

delete it along with node_modules and reinstall packages.

Comment: Well, sort of, not really... Reinstalling node_modules did not work. Apparently my package.json resolved into dependencies that don't work together. 

Fortunately, I has a spare node_mdules env of a staging environment that DID work. I shinkwrapped this and installed that specifc version. It now works again but I suspect that there was some API imcompatiblity between previous versions of some libs.

Comment: did you have package.lock.json when reinstalling node_modules?
I've seen dozens of questions with "broken" builds which all came down to npm issues.. 
nothing to do with aurelia.

Comment: No package.lock.json.

Comment: shrinkwrap then.. 
the gist is that it is a package manager problem